# Keras val_acc unchanging when training (same label assigned to all images)

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, cnn

I am using Keras to make a "set" identifier for the card game *[Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(game))*.

Here is my script (some code may be unnecessary but was used during experimentation):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.regularizers import l2

import os
import glob
import shutil

import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, patience=5,
                          verbose=1, mode='auto')

callbacks_list = [earlystop]

# opt = SGD(lr=0.01)

setIdentifier = Sequential()

setIdentifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

setIdentifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

setIdentifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# setIdentifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

setIdentifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

setIdentifier.add(Flatten())

setIdentifier.add(Dense(units=256, activation = 'relu'))

setIdentifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))

setIdentifier.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax"))

setIdentifier.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                shear_range = 0.2, 
                zoom_range = 0.2, 
                horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data_Training', 
                                                target_size = (64, 64),
                                                batch_size = 32,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data_Testing',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

setIdentifier.fit_generator(training_set, 
                                steps_per_epoch = 486,
                                epochs = 50, 
                                validation_data = test_set,
                                validation_steps = 60,
                                callbacks = callbacks_list)

setIdentifier.save("setIdentifier.h5")
```

The file `Data_Training` has a folder `notSet` and a folder `Set`, and the file `Data_Testing` likewise. There are two times as many `notSets` than `Sets` in each category.

No matter what I do, in both training and testing phases, the output is always `notSet`. I am not sure what is the cause for this.

I have tried a `binary_classifier` with the sigmoid activation function and final density layer with 1 node. I have tried changing activation functions and using `leakyRelus`.

I have double checked my training steps and test steps.
I have $5184\text{ sets }+ 2 \cdot 5184\text{ notSet = }15552$ train images, which when divided by a batch size of $32$ gets me $486$ steps.
I have $648\text{ Sets }+ 2 \cdot 648\text{ notSet = }60.75$ >> rounded to $60$ validation steps.

I am confused by what is going on with the neural network - why isn't anything approving and why is it labelling everything with one class?

For more info, [here is the Github repo](https://github.com/Keyan-Rhm/MLWithSet) which includes the training images.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: from 256 you are going to 2; try going from 256->64->8->2? And remove half of the -ve classes(though it shouldn't matter)